# How to send a contact me email from my rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, mailer

It seems like such a simple thing, I don't want to use devise or any users for that matter, this is my personal website, where I display my work. All I want to do is make a contact me email form so that I can recieve messages from the people that visit my site. All of the tutorial that I have encountered send the email TO the user.

When I try to create an email. This is what I get:

SMTP-AUTH requested but missing user name

```
@contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
@contact.request = request
if @contact.deliver
  flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you, I will contact you soon.'
  redirect_to root_path
else
```

this is my contact controller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    @contact.request = request
    if @contact.valid?
      ContactMe.contact_email(@contact).deliver
      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:notice] = "Message sent from {@contact.name}"
    else     
      render :new
      flash.now[:error] = 'Could not send message as is. Please check email and phone fields.'
    end
  end
end
```

contact model:

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :message


  # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
  # in ActionMailer accepts.
  def headers
    {
      :subject => "Contact",
      :to => "literallymyemail@gmail.com",
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end

class ContactMe < ApplicationMailer

  def contact_email(contact)
    @contact = contact
    mail(to: 'literallymyemail@gmail.com', from: @contact.email, :subject => "Website Contact")
  end
end
```

production.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'nicolasdev.herokuapp.com' }
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",  
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => 'gmail.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :user_name            => ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    :password             => ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
    :authentication       => "plain"

  }

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '*.jpg', '*.png', '*.gif', '*.ico'] 

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

application.yml:

```
GMAIL_USERNAME: 'literallymyemail@gmail.com'
GMAIL_PASSWORD: 'literallymyemailpassword'
```

I am probably making numerous mistakes, but please have mercy on me. I have been at this for some time, lurking about other posts and tutorials to no avail.

Comment: There's an e-mail stack beyond Rails that has to be installed and configured before you'll be able to send mail. Heroku apps can use Sendgrid very easily, but you have to enable it. Have you added Sendgrid to your Heroku app?

Comment: I did not know about it. I will do some research. This was not discussed in any of the tutorials

Comment: Here's a good place to start: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid

Comment: Here's where Heroku specifies that you need an external SMTP server to interact with https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the tips on sendgrid, that was probably the next thing that I was going to bash my head agaist. Thank you for saving me the headache. My problem was deeper than this though. It seems that one of my gems was dependent on sql3 which was causing it not update my controller. I never noticed that I was not pushing my changes (oops!) I actually noticed it after I saw my own post and saw the difference in the error log and the controller in my github. Don't know how useful this question will be for the community, but who knows... Thank you for you help.